# Android: Checking Background Resource Drawable

Tags: android, background, resources, drawable

Please help how can we do a Background Resource Check?

Example:

```
  Button button1;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ..........................................
  button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.example1);
  }

  public void onclick1 (View v){
         button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.example2);
  }

  public void onclick2 (View v){
```

My Question Here, checking if button1 button drawable = example2

```
        if (..........................){
               //Action
        }
```

If not, when clicked will done another action

```
        else {
               //Another Action
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`getBackground()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBackground%28%29) method of the View class for both buttons and compare it like this:

```
if (button1.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(button2.getBackground().getConstantState())) {
    }
else {
    }
```